# How can i tell if my npgsql/conntion is to a readonly database?

Tags: npgsql

I am connecting to a postgres database.  I do not know  beforehand if the instance of the database is a readonly copy.  The code is in c# and I am using npgsql to make the connection.    Is there someflag that shows the read write or read only status of the database?  I am using npgsql 4.03

We have a main read write copy of the database and multiple copies of read only databases.  This is all postgres on aws.  The multiple read only copies are for scalability.  I have found  a postgres command "pg_is_in_recovery".  This does work, return true when read only and false when writeable.  But this is a problem for npgsql when closing a connection.  Part of the cleanup from npgsql is to issue an "unlisten *" command.  The unlisten actually tries to insert a row, which fails because the database is readonly.  ( AWS Documentation » Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) » User Guide » PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS

PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS -- calls this a Read Replica

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "readonly copy" of the database?

Comment: a read replica.   I have expounded the question text above...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to modify the source ( npgsql ) so that after a connection has been made the state of the PostGres database ( Read/Write or ReadOnly ) is kept in the npgsql connection.  @ Shay Rojanskyor others on the team.  How do i submit this branch for a merge  to the main branch ?